# Protractor - wait for repeater elements

Tags: javascript, protractor, wait, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm using Protractor for e2e test. currently I'm using a lot of workflow timeouts. I want to replace it with `browser.wait`. the problem is that I don't always know what to wait for. for example when switching to other frame.
this specific question is for waiting for repeater elements to show.
this is my current code:

```
   flow.timeout(5000);

   element.all(by.repeater('whatsNewItem in homePageWhatsNewItems')).count().then(function (firstCount) {

    console.log("number of WhatsNew=" + firstCount);
    expect(firstCount >= 5).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I want to replace the `flow.timeout` in `browser.wait(.....)`
any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what element to wait for then its easy to use protractor's [`ExpectedConditions`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) to wait for an element to appear on the page. Here's how -

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var repeaterElement = element(by.repeater('whatsNewItem in homePageWhatsNewItems'));

//Wait up to 10 seconds for elements to be visible
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(repeaterElement), 10000) 
.then(function(){
    //Perform any operation that you want after waiting for the element to appear
});
```

If at all you don't know which element to wait for, then check the element that loads at the end always and wait for that element to appear. By this way, errors can be avoided. Hope it helps.

Comment: seems like it works. Thanks! only one thing - it should be 'element(by.repeater...' - exclude the 'all'.

Comment: @user2880391 updated the code. I thought you had many repeaters in your HTML DOM. If it helped you kindly mark it as answer. Thanks.